# Contact Cursor Returning NullPointerException

Tags: android, sms, cursor, android-contacts

I am using Following Code to get the contact name for sms in inbox. When i try following code it works well till some extend but give NullPointerException after fetching half of Names:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_smscontacts);
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    Cursor cur=null;

    int Count=0;
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String address=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
        if (address != null) 
        {
            Uri person=Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(address));
            String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME };
            cur=getContentResolver().query(person, projection, null, null, null);
            if(cur.moveToNext())
            {
                Log.i("Name", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                Log.i("count", Count++ + "");
            }
            else
                Log.i("cursor", "Null" + address);
        }
        else
            Log.i("address", "Null");

    }
    cur.close();
    cursor.close();
    Log.i("count", Count + "");

}
```

LogCat is as folowing:

```
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lovish.smscontactsdummy/com.lovish.smscontactsdummy.SMSContactsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2081)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1217)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at com.lovish.smscontactsdummy.SMSContactsActivity.onCreate(SMSContactsActivity.java:38)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2045)
06-29 15:04:41.509: E/AndroidRuntime(28700):    ... 11 more
```

Please help me out need its solution..!!

Comment: after the query, you could try putting a check to see if cur=null before calling cur.moveToNext().

Comment: Nopes Same issue again...it entered after checking cur=null in earlier messages but stucks again and started returning cur as null..

Comment: maybe you could try while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) and then put the cursor.moveToNext() at the bottom of the loop

Comment: Which cursor are you seeing the error in ? Post logcat as well

Comment: @Android Noob....Still same issue

Comment: @SlartibartFast.....Error is in inner cursor i.e. cur and i placed logcat as well...

Comment: I need to try out this code to see what's wrong.  I've used custom Content Providers but I haven't used anything that accessed something that's built into the device.  Are you running this on a phone?

Comment: @Android Noob ...Yeah i am running this on my phone...if you could try n help with this i would be great...:)

Comment: really quick...did you try calling cursor.moveToFirst() after each query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `while` loop, as a quick fix put this:

```
    if (cur != null)
        cur.close();
```

When in doubt, use your debugger.  I diagnosed the issue in Eclipse in less than a minute...

Comment: Thank you so much it worked...:)
i do use debugger...but i did encountered such kind of errors till today..so trying to learn more day by day...:)